# Бот для игры Minecraft

Tags: minecraft

Интересует на чем может быть написан бот для игры майнкрафт (сторонние лаунчеры проектов, если интересно)
О проекте: есть мини-игра на одном известном проекте где нужно копать блоки и повышать уровень. Помимо этого есть отрицательные эффекты. Тошнота - нужно встать в воду на некоторое время. Медлительность - кликнуть по рычагу.
Недавно видел такого, бот как-то считывал из игры что появился эффект тошноты, или допустим медлительности и начинал убирать эти эффекты автоматически.
Так вот, интересует как это могли сделать?

Comment: Sorry, вы хотите чтоб за вас сейчас написали бота? Берёте, учите Java(думаю для +- норм бота 1го года изучения хватит) пишите на нём мод и всё.

Comment: нет, мне нужно просто узнать на каком это языке возможно

Comment: да и моды туда не загрузить, это лаунчер проекта

Comment: возможно, конечно, что кто-то нашёл обход и всё же загрузил своего бота через папку модс=)

Comment: я вам уже ответил что учить. И с чего вы решили что не можете модифицировать "лаунчер проекта" ?

Comment: У сына есть книга - программирование в Minecraft на Java. Языки там определены - Java + Python

Comment: могу, но лаунчер каждый раз проверяет папку и удаляет лишнего возвращая всё к первоначальному виду, как было задумано разработчиком изначально)

Comment: @hAKowO3jQWM1s С таким набором данных вам здесь ничем не помогут. Мало того что вы некорректно задали вопрос таки ещё сами ничего не понимаете. Идите смотрите, читайте, познавайте контент на тему "свой бот в minecraft"

Comment: да я на самом деле уже давно ищу. не было бы проблемой если бы это был простой мод под лаунчер без проверок, но всё же спасибо